# Unable to install sklearn in virtual environment on windows - ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:

Tags: scikit-learn, python-venv

Can anyone help me install sklearn to windows virtual environment?

The normal way to do this would be

**Method 1 - pip install into empty environment**

```
python -m venv venv
.\venv\Scripts\activate.bat
pip install sklearn
```

**Method 2 - create virtual environment with system settings**

or if sklearn is already installed on your operating system, this method

```
python -m venv venv --system-site-packages
.\venv\Scripts\activate.bat
```

Both methods produce errors when I try pip installs, or say sklearn module missing if I try and run python/flask file

**pip install methods tried**

From the command line I have tried

```
pip install sklearn
```

I also have tried to install sklearn via requirements.txt file

```
pip install -r requirements.txt
```

I have also tried to isolate the part of sklearn that I need

```
pip install -U scikit-learn scipy linear_model
```

I have also tried

```
pip3 install sklearn
```

The error I am getting runs into several pages

> Collecting sklearn   Using cached sklearn-0.0.tar.gz (1.1 kB) Collecting scikit-learn   Using cached scikit-learn-0.23.2.tar.gz (7.2
> MB)   Installing build dependencies ... error   ERROR: Command errored
> out with exit status 1:    command:
> 'c:\users\owner\desktop\machine_learning_project\venv\scripts\python.exe'
> 'c:\users\owner\desktop\machine_learning_project\venv\lib\site-packages\pip'
> install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix
> 'C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-whbbbe7h\overlay'
> --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.28.5'
> 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and
> platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"' and platform_python_implementation ==
> '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and
> platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"' and platform_python_implementation !=
> '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and
> platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3;
> python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"''
> 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and
> platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0;
> python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"''
> 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and
> platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'scipy>=0.19.1'
> cwd: None   Complete output (280 lines):   Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and platform_system != "AIX" and
> platform_python_implementation == "CPython"' don't match your
> environment   Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6" and
> platform_system != "AIX" and platform_python_implementation !=
> "CPython"' don't match your environment   Ignoring numpy: markers
> 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system != "AIX"' don't match
> your environment   Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.6"
> and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment   Ignoring
> numpy: markers 'python_version == "3.7" and platform_system == "AIX"'
> don't match your environment   Ignoring numpy: markers 'python_version
>
> > = "3.8" and platform_system == "AIX"' don't match your environment   Collecting setuptools
> > Using cached setuptools-50.3.2-py3-none-any.whl (785 kB)   Collecting wheel
> > Using cached wheel-0.35.1-py2.py3-none-any.whl (33 kB)   Collecting Cython>=0.28.5
> > Using cached Cython-0.29.21-py2.py3-none-any.whl (974 kB)   Collecting numpy==1.17.3
> > Using cached numpy-1.17.3.zip (6.4 MB)   Collecting scipy>=0.19.1
> > Using cached scipy-1.5.4-cp39-cp39-win_amd64.whl (31.4 MB)   Using legacy 'setup.py install' for numpy, since package 'wheel' is not
> > installed.   Installing collected packages: setuptools, wheel, Cython,
> > numpy, scipy
> > Running setup.py install for numpy: started
> > Running setup.py install for numpy: finished with status 'error'
> > ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> > command: 'c:\users\owner\desktop\machine_learning_project\venv\scripts\python.exe'
> > -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-geaq7_mw\numpy\setup.py'"'"';
> > **file**='"'"'C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-geaq7_mw\numpy\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
> > '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> > '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> > install --record
> > 'C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-_06ilpk2\install-record.txt'
> > --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-whbbbe7h\overlay'
> > --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-whbbbe7h\overlay\include\site\python3.9\numpy'
> > cwd: C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-geaq7_mw\numpy
> > Complete output (254 lines):
> > Running from numpy source directory.
>
> ```
>   Note: if you need reliable uninstall behavior, then install
>   with pip instead of using `setup.py install`:
>
>     - `pip install .`       (from a git repo or downloaded source
>                              release)
>     - `pip install numpy`   (last NumPy release on PyPi)
>
>
>   blas_opt_info:
>   blas_mkl_info:
>   No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
>   customize MSVCCompiler
>     libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\owner\\desktop\\machine_learning_project\\venv\\lib',
> ```
>
> 'C:\']
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> ```
>   blis_info:
>   No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
>   customize MSVCCompiler
>     libraries blis not found in ['c:\\users\\owner\\desktop\\machine_learning_project\\venv\\lib',
> ```
>
> 'C:\']
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> ```
>   openblas_info:
>   No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
>   customize MSVCCompiler
>   No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
>   customize MSVCCompiler
>     libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\owner\\desktop\\machine_learning_project\\venv\\lib',
> ```
>
> 'C:\']
> get_default_fcompiler: matching types: '['gnu', 'intelv', 'absoft', 'compaqv', 'intelev', 'gnu95', 'g95', 'intelvem', 'intelem',
> 'flang']'
> customize GnuFCompiler
> Could not locate executable g77
> Could not locate executable f77
> customize IntelVisualFCompiler
> Could not locate executable ifort
> Could not locate executable ifl
> customize AbsoftFCompiler
> Could not locate executable f90
> customize CompaqVisualFCompiler
> Found executable C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\DF.exe
> Could not locate executable C:\Program
> customize IntelItaniumVisualFCompiler
> Could not locate executable efl
> customize Gnu95FCompiler
> Could not locate executable gfortran
> Could not locate executable f95
> customize G95FCompiler
> Could not locate executable g95
> customize IntelEM64VisualFCompiler
> customize IntelEM64TFCompiler
> Could not locate executable efort
> Could not locate executable efc
> customize PGroupFlangCompiler
> Could not locate executable flang
> don't know how to compile Fortran code on platform 'nt'
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> ```
>   atlas_3_10_blas_threads_info:
>   Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
>   No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
>   customize MSVCCompiler
>     libraries tatlas not found in ['c:\\users\\owner\\desktop\\machine_learning_project\\venv\\lib',
> ```
>
> 'C:\']
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> ```
>   atlas_3_10_blas_info:
>   No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
>   customize MSVCCompiler
>     libraries satlas not found in ['c:\\users\\owner\\desktop\\machine_learning_project\\venv\\lib',
> ```
>
> 'C:\']
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> ```
>   atlas_blas_threads_info:
>   Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
>   No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
>   customize MSVCCompiler
>     libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\owner\\desktop\\machine_learning_project\\venv\\lib',
> ```
>
> 'C:\']
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> ```
>   atlas_blas_info:
>   No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
>   customize MSVCCompiler
>     libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in ['c:\\users\\owner\\desktop\\machine_learning_project\\venv\\lib',
> ```
>
> 'C:\']
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> ```
>   accelerate_info:
>     NOT AVAILABLE
>
>   C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-geaq7_mw\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690:
> ```
>
> UserWarning:
> Optimized (vendor) Blas libraries are not found.
> Falls back to netlib Blas library which has worse performance.
> A better performance should be easily gained by switching
> Blas library.
> self.calc_info()
> blas_info:
> No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
> customize MSVCCompiler
> libraries blas not found in ['c:\users\owner\desktop\machine_learning_project\venv\lib',
> 'C:\']
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> ```
>   C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-geaq7_mw\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690:
> ```
>
> UserWarning:
> Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) libraries not found.
> Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
> numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas]) or by setting
> the BLAS environment variable.
> self.calc_info()
> blas_src_info:
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> ```
>   C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-geaq7_mw\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:690:
> ```
>
> UserWarning:
> Blas (http://www.netlib.org/blas/) sources not found.
> Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
> numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [blas_src]) or by setting
> the BLAS_SRC environment variable.
> self.calc_info()
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> ```
>   'svnversion' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
>   operable program or batch file.
>   non-existing path in 'numpy\\distutils': 'site.cfg'
>   lapack_opt_info:
>   lapack_mkl_info:
>   No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
>   customize MSVCCompiler
>     libraries mkl_rt not found in ['c:\\users\\owner\\desktop\\machine_learning_project\\venv\\lib',
> ```
>
> 'C:\']
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> ```
>   openblas_lapack_info:
>   No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
>   customize MSVCCompiler
>   No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
>   customize MSVCCompiler
>     libraries openblas not found in ['c:\\users\\owner\\desktop\\machine_learning_project\\venv\\lib',
> ```
>
> 'C:\']
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> ```
>   openblas_clapack_info:
>   No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
>   customize MSVCCompiler
>   No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
>   customize MSVCCompiler
>     libraries openblas,lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\owner\\desktop\\machine_learning_project\\venv\\lib',
> ```
>
> 'C:\']
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> ```
>   flame_info:
>   No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
>   customize MSVCCompiler
>     libraries flame not found in ['c:\\users\\owner\\desktop\\machine_learning_project\\venv\\lib',
> ```
>
> 'C:\']
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> ```
>   atlas_3_10_threads_info:
>   Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
>   No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
>   customize MSVCCompiler
>     libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\owner\desktop\machine_learning_project\venv\lib
>   No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
>   customize MSVCCompiler
>     libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in c:\users\owner\desktop\machine_learning_project\venv\lib
>   No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
>   customize MSVCCompiler
>     libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
>   No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
>   customize MSVCCompiler
>     libraries tatlas,tatlas not found in C:\
>   <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_threads_info'>
>     NOT AVAILABLE
>
>   atlas_3_10_info:
>   No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
>   customize MSVCCompiler
>     libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\owner\desktop\machine_learning_project\venv\lib
>   No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
>   customize MSVCCompiler
>     libraries satlas,satlas not found in c:\users\owner\desktop\machine_learning_project\venv\lib
>   No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
>   customize MSVCCompiler
>     libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
>   No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
>   customize MSVCCompiler
>     libraries satlas,satlas not found in C:\
>   <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_3_10_info'>
>     NOT AVAILABLE
>
>   atlas_threads_info:
>   Setting PTATLAS=ATLAS
>   No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
>   customize MSVCCompiler
>     libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\owner\desktop\machine_learning_project\venv\lib
>   No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
>   customize MSVCCompiler
>     libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in c:\users\owner\desktop\machine_learning_project\venv\lib
>   No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
>   customize MSVCCompiler
>     libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
>   No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
>   customize MSVCCompiler
>     libraries ptf77blas,ptcblas,atlas not found in C:\
>   <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_threads_info'>
>     NOT AVAILABLE
>
>   atlas_info:
>   No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
>   customize MSVCCompiler
>     libraries lapack_atlas not found in c:\users\owner\desktop\machine_learning_project\venv\lib
>   No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
>   customize MSVCCompiler
>     libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in c:\users\owner\desktop\machine_learning_project\venv\lib
>   No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
>   customize MSVCCompiler
>     libraries lapack_atlas not found in C:\
>   No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
>   customize MSVCCompiler
>     libraries f77blas,cblas,atlas not found in C:\
>   <class 'numpy.distutils.system_info.atlas_info'>
>     NOT AVAILABLE
>
>   lapack_info:
>   No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
>   customize MSVCCompiler
>     libraries lapack not found in ['c:\\users\\owner\\desktop\\machine_learning_project\\venv\\lib',
> ```
>
> 'C:\']
> NOT AVAILABLE
>
> ```
>   C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-geaq7_mw\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1712:
> ```
>
> UserWarning:
>
> ```
>       Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) libraries not found.
>       Directories to search for the libraries can be specified in the
>       numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack]) or by setting
>       the LAPACK environment variable.
>     if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
>   lapack_src_info:
>     NOT AVAILABLE
>
>   C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-geaq7_mw\numpy\numpy\distutils\system_info.py:1712:
> ```
>
> UserWarning:
>
> ```
>       Lapack (http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) sources not found.
>       Directories to search for the sources can be specified in the
>       numpy/distutils/site.cfg file (section [lapack_src]) or by setting
>       the LAPACK_SRC environment variable.
>     if getattr(self, '_calc_info_{}'.format(lapack))():
>     NOT AVAILABLE
>
>   C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\distutils\dist.py:274:
> ```
>
> UserWarning: Unknown distribution option: 'define_macros'
> warnings.warn(msg)
> running install
> running build
> running config_cc
> unifing config_cc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --compiler options
> running config_fc
> unifing config_fc, config, build_clib, build_ext, build commands --fcompiler options
> running build_src
> build_src
> building py_modules sources
> creating build
> creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9
> creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy
> creating build\src.win-amd64-3.9\numpy\distutils
> building library "npymath" sources
> No module named 'numpy.distutils._msvccompiler' in numpy.distutils; trying from distutils
> error: Microsoft Visual C++ 14.0 or greater is required. Get it with "Microsoft C++ Build Tools":
> https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/visual-cpp-build-tools/
> ----------------------------------------   ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> 'c:\users\owner\desktop\machine_learning_project\venv\scripts\python.exe'
> -u -c 'import sys, setuptools, tokenize; sys.argv[0] = '"'"'C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-geaq7_mw\numpy\setup.py'"'"';
> **file**='"'"'C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-geaq7_mw\numpy\setup.py'"'"';f=getattr(tokenize,
> '"'"'open'"'"', open)(**file**);code=f.read().replace('"'"'\r\n'"'"',
> '"'"'\n'"'"');f.close();exec(compile(code, **file**, '"'"'exec'"'"'))'
> install --record
> 'C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-_06ilpk2\install-record.txt'
> --single-version-externally-managed --prefix 'C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-whbbbe7h\overlay'
> --compile --install-headers 'C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-whbbbe7h\overlay\include\site\python3.9\numpy'
> Check the logs for full command output.
> ---------------------------------------- ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
> 'c:\users\owner\desktop\machine_learning_project\venv\scripts\python.exe'
> 'c:\users\owner\desktop\machine_learning_project\venv\lib\site-packages\pip'
> install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix
> 'C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-whbbbe7h\overlay'
> --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools wheel 'Cython>=0.28.5'
> 'numpy==1.13.3; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and
> platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"' and platform_python_implementation ==
> '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and
> platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"' and platform_python_implementation !=
> '"'"'CPython'"'"'' 'numpy==1.14.5; python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and
> platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.17.3;
> python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and platform_system!='"'"'AIX'"'"''
> 'numpy==1.16.0; python_version=='"'"'3.6'"'"' and
> platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'numpy==1.16.0;
> python_version=='"'"'3.7'"'"' and platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"''
> 'numpy==1.17.3; python_version>='"'"'3.8'"'"' and
> platform_system=='"'"'AIX'"'"'' 'scipy>=0.19.1' Check the logs for
> full command output.

Answer (score 1):

Your error says all"

follow steps.

```
pip install numpy
```

and later

```
pip install scikit-learn
```

as numpy is the requirement.